# Cannot connect to IdentityController in IdentityServer4 Quickstart

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-3.1

I receive an "actively refused" message when I execute this line of code in the console client.  (Note that the discovery works and is directed to port 60540).

```
  var c = new HttpClient();
  c.SetBearerToken(tr.AccessToken);
  var rsp = await c.GetAsync("http://localhost:5000/identity");
```

Below is my launchSettings.json

```
  {
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:60540",
      "sslPort": 44386
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "commandLineArgs": "debug=true",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Service": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000"
    }
  }
}
```

Below is relevant code from Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices (IServiceCollection services)
{
  IIdentityServerBuilder                    isb;

  services.AddControllers();
  services.AddAuthentication("Bearer").AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
  {
    options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.Audience = "api1";
  });
  isb = services.AddIdentityServer();
  isb.AddInMemoryIdentityResources(new List<IdentityResource>
  {
    new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
    new IdentityResources.Profile()
  }).
  AddInMemoryApiResources(new List<ApiResource>()
  {
    new ApiResource("api1", "My Api")
  }).
  AddInMemoryClients(new List<Client>()
  {
    new Client
    {
      ClientId = "client",
      AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
      ClientSecrets =
      {
        new Secret("secret".Sha256())
      },
      AllowedScopes =
      {
        "api1"
      }
    }
  });
  // not recommended for production - you need to store your key material somewhere secure
  isb.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
}   /* method Startup ConfigureServices */

public void Configure (IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
  if (env.IsDevelopment())
  {
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
  }
  app.UseStaticFiles();
  app.UseRouting();
  app.UseIdentityServer();
  app.UseAuthentication();
  app.UseAuthorization();
  app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
  {
    endpoints.MapControllers();
  });
}   /* method Startup Configure */
```

I have tried the IIS Express profile and the Service Profile and the results are the same.  I started this project as a VS 2019 Worker Service project for aspnet core 3.1

Comment: Be sure that applicationUrl of your launchSettings.json in web api is 5000.Refer to:http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html    Here is a github example:https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/master/samples/Quickstarts/1_ClientCredentials/src

Comment: @rena - I included my launchsettings above.  I have 5000 in there.  Does it look correct?

Comment: set `sslPort:0` and call api:`http://localhost:60540`.

Answer (score 0):

since you said that discovery work on port 60540, 
have you tried to access  http://localhost:60540/identity ?